# How do I install cinnamon on Ubuntu server?

Tags: 12.04, dependencies, cinnamon, mate

How do I install cinnamon and mate on ubuntu server 12.04?
What are the dependencies?

When I install cinnamon it doesn't start when I start the system and when I try to use it with startx command i shows a "Failed to load session "ubuntu" " error while entering the desktop GUI.
With MATE it also doesn't start automatically and when I start it with startx some icons are broken and the locale appears to have some problems with the pt_BR special characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop) (the fact that it is a server install does not really matter)

Comment: Actually I've already seen it. My problem is installing it in Ubuntu Server in Ubuntu Desktop I had no problems.

Comment: Please update the question with your problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install MATE?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87040/how-to-install-mate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on my company server and I was searching alternatives for days before I get my problem solved with MATE.

That's what I did:

1. Manually install the minimal packages for get X running on my host.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xserver-org-core
   ```
2. Follow the instructions from this post: (I just needed a minimal GUI so I just get installed  the `mate-core` package)

   http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/howto-install-mate-on-ubuntu-12-04-with-no-other-desktop-environments-942438/
3. I needed my server starts on CLI with NO GUI, so I don't install any display manager (gdm, kdm, etc). so if you need start server on a GUI try to build the Mate-display-manager from the source.
4. After installation of MATE maybe you want to install some tools.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mate-system-tools mate-text-editor mozo mate-utils
   ```
5. Of course, you can install some useful tools from Gnome

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends synaptic gparted firefox system-config-lvm
   ```

This is it, reboot server, log on and run `startx`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. MATE I've already installed with success. Now the problem is the other distro with cinnamon that I can't make it work.

Answer (score 3):

What I did after server install (I installed ssh and samba) is to install xserver-xorg-core then add the "cinnamon" repository to "sources and installed cinnamon and xinit.

I got the same error so what I ran

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start
```

It started up fine, rebooted and now lightdm starts automatically

Comment: This worked for me. But I had to use `startx` instead of `lightdm`

Answer (score 1):

A lazy solution would be first install [Ubuntu Desktop](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-desktop) (`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`) and then proceed as [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) has [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/94202/12943).

Comment: Thank you, but I want to make two simple "distros" one only with Cinnamon and the other only with MATE. That is for machines with less resources and for those that don't like the newest interfaces like Gnome 3 and the hateful Unity.

Comment: Looks like a dependency problem. We must find which packages are required for the Cinnamon and MATE to run. Have you installed the xserver and lightdm (or gdm)?