# Getting a Linux Mint graphical interface on Ubuntu 12.04.2 Server

Tags: installation, boot, server, software-recommendation

After successful installation of Ubuntu 12.04.2, a change is needed from graphics-less Ubuntu server terminal-style interface to a [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) graphical interface.

I have booted with an inserted Linux Mint 15 [Cinnamon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_%28user_interface%29) install disc. I had no response beyond an initial prompt between similar "Ubuntu with Linux" options that led to operation just like it was without a disc-inserted-boot without a directed Linux installation.

This situation is Ubuntu server operating on 160 GB of 320 GB with an operator who's inexperienced with terminal-style interfaces and a need for a graphical interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be cinnamon that you install on the machine?

Try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

That will install cinnamon (the Mint desktop) on your machine.
If it can be any other desktop environment (XFCE is nice, lightweight and easy to use) you can use

```
sudo apt-get install <desktop name>
```

e.g. xubuntu-desktop lubuntu-desktop or kubuntu-desktop for XFCE, LXDE and KDE respectively

EDIT: This website has a tutorial for installing it

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/04/26/install-the-latest-and-greatest-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: You beat me to it! To add, here's some more detailed information on it, complete with pictures - http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/09/20/install-cinnamon-1-6-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Comment: Cinnamon isn't the only option, but I have it within reach on a disc.  

My goals before getting an easy to use desktop were access to a word processor, and an internet browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install one graphical interface in Ubuntu Server, you can install one with one of these commands depending of the flavour that you want (I ordered them by own criteria for a server, being the first the one with less resources use):

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

And if you want to install Cinnamon or Mate as a Mint interface, you can do this:

> 1. Manually install the minimal packages for get X running on my host.
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install xserver-org-core
>    ```
> 2. Follow the instructions from this post: (I just needed a minimal GUI so I just get installed  the `mate-core` package)
>
>    http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/howto-install-mate-on-ubuntu-12-04-with-no-other-desktop-environments-942438/
> 3. I needed my server starts on CLI with NO GUI, so I don't install any display manager (gdm, kdm, etc). so if you need start server on a
>      GUI try to build the Mate-display-manager from the source.
> 4. After installation of MATE maybe you want to install some tools.
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install mate-system-tools mate-text-editor mozo mate-utils
>    ```
> 5. Of course, you can install some useful tools from Gnome
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends synaptic gparted firefox system-config-lvm
>    ```
>
> This is it, reboot server, log on and run `startx`

Source: [How do I install cinnamon on Ubuntu server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132270/how-do-i-install-cinnamon-on-ubuntu-server)

Comment: How to return to the Ubuntu Server after entering graphical interface installation commands?

Comment: Modifying GRUB as here is specified: http://askubuntu.com/questions/196603/how-to-remove-the-graphical-user-interface

Comment: Or simplily pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 (or F2, or whathever F+number, each one is an instance of a terminal)