# Ubuntu - Install Mate Desktop - Themes missing?

Tags: 12.04, mate

I just installed Mate on top of Ubuntu by the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu oneiric main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-archive-keyring
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-core
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment
```

Which caused no problems, but many things (window theme, Mint menu, ...) are missing.

It looks like:

[image: a]

But it should look like:

[image: b]

How can I install the missing packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATE by default is similar to a vanilla GNOME 2.x install. This means you won't get the Mint menu, etc. unless you install those separately, most likely by adding Mint repos to your system (but note this could potentially cause problems).

General information on how to install MATE can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/87040/18612). If you want to install Mint's version of it, you could try following the steps which will add the Mint repos to your sources list [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/87042/18612).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install mate-themes
```