# Gnome Classic or Gnome 2

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gtk-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install MATE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87040/how-to-install-mate)

How to change 3rd Gnome Classic version to 2nd with gtk2 (or just make somehow gtk2)? Or how to make in Gnome 2 the same task panel as Unity's in Ubuntu 12.04? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to degrade Gnome 3 classic to Gnome 2. Since Unity and Gnome 2 are different desktop , It is not possible to make Gnome panel as Unity's. Unity's panel developed using it specific packages that may not suitable with Gnome 2.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the option of installing [MATE](http://mate-desktop.org/). It's basically a fork of Gnome 2.x, and it supports recent versions of Ubuntu, Mint, Debian, Fedora, etc.

Comment: I know about Mate, but i need it with the Unity's panel. By the way, i mean not that panel with main menu, just the upper task panel with clock, turn off button.. Any ways to make the same panel in the 2nd Gnome (Mate)? Maybe anyone knows how to convert the gtk2 theme to gtk3 or make the gtk3 theme as i want?

Answer (score 0):

You could install gnome classic on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

And when you are going to enter your password on the greeter screen, Click on Ubuntu icon near your username, and select "Gnome Classic"

Comment: xkill,
I know, that Gnome with gtk3, but i need with gtk2.