# Is "Mate" an available desktop environment on Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04 and attractive as on the LinuxMint 14?

Tags: desktop-environments, mate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install MATE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87040/how-to-install-mate)

I am wondering if Mate can be installed on Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04 without any glitches and bugs? I have tried it using LinuxMint and it is fairly attractive there and stable too, but I'd like to stick to Ubuntu.

Thanks.