# Can't Upgrade My Old Ubuntu System

Tags: upgrade, system

I have a really old ubuntu system. Probably somewhere around 2.0.3 or something. i went to update manager but it wont let me download the new system. I have tried looking online for individual downloads to work my way up to the software but i can't find them. I also have a lot of important things on my computer so i can't "crash it" and "redownload ubuntu" Is there any way to upgrade my system or am i just screwed...?

Comment: First, save all the important stuff on a USB hard drive. Do that even if you could do a normal distribution upgrade. After you get that done, you need to investigate your system. It's possible that your old system won't run a new version of Ubuntu. I don't know why you can't at least download the newest version, but find out what you have and post details here. Then somebody can help you see what's possible.

Comment: You sure you are using Ubuntu? What's the output of `lsb_release -ds` in a terminal?

Comment: I assume you have 8.04.3 or 10.04.3?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [Ubuntu ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and burn it in a CD.
2. Boot your computer from the CD.
3. Choose install Ubuntu.
4. There will be three options.
   (i) Upgrade the old version of Ubuntu.
   (ii) Replace the old version of Ubuntu with the new version.
   (iii) Something Else
5. Choose upgrade and it will keep all your files. It could also upgrade some programmes if  your computer is connected to internet.

Comment: If your computer runs slow then you can download [MATE Desktop Environment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87040/how-to-install-mate).