# Does Ubuntu comes with MATE flavor?

Tags: mate

I know about Linux Mint, but is there any 'Ubuntu' out there with MATE?

Comment: Not a duplicate as I don't think there is a version of Ubuntu with mate pre-installed. But you can install it see [How to install MATE?](http://askubuntu.com/q/87040/107450)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one sourceforge project from where you can get the MATE edition of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
[sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntumate/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntumate/)

Answer (score 3):

[Ubuntu MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org) is a respin of Ubuntu that uses the MATE desktop environment, and became an official Ubuntu flavor starting with 15.04, "Vivid Vervet."