# Any Other Distros with Gnome 2.32?

Tags: gnome, distro-recommendation

I've used Ubuntu for almost a year and I don't like the Unity environment and I installed BackTrack R3 in my laptop which uses GNOME 2.32 and I'm much impressed with that and made a decision to move to GNOME but, it is currently in version 3.x and it has been said that there is no GNOME 2.x versions are supported.

I don't like the new GNOME and surfed the internet for finding a distro with that version and support. But, I can't find one. Can you specify a good distro with GNOME 2.x and Debian package installers?

Comment: Gowtham , currently no Ubuntu Distros are providing Gnome2.x . But we can help you more If you be more specific about what you want.

Comment: I also don't like the Unity interface so I use gnome fallback (or what it's called) In Ubuntu 13.10. It looks better than point linux which I think is quite ugly... I can put it as an answer and provide screenshots, unless the power goes out(a storm is coming in).. :)

Comment: @rajagenupula I find myself productive with Gnome 2.x - but there is no support for it except Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. I'm seeking to get a distro with gnome 2.x and debian...

Comment: @Alvar why you're saying that point linux is ugly? can you be specific?

Comment: @Gowtham answer updated :)

Comment: added my answer (still got power even though the storm is at it peak (30m/s winds)). :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What different desktop environments and shells are available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would install any version of Ubuntu you like 12.04/13.10 and install Ubuntu fallback. Also known as the classic desktop. It's similar to MATE and Point Linux but has a more modern look. Instructions on how to install it is available [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/65087/10698)

Answer (score 3):

well you can install Point Linux , it also uses Gnome 2.x only. I have read the Doc at it official site : http://pointlinux.org/

its also Debian based Linux.

Screen shots:They are different languages.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**@OP As I have seen **

- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Desktop supports ,May 9 2013 ( Reached EOL already)
- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server supports, April 2015 ( We have two more years)

So you can install Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server edition (http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ for download links) and then

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

will install gnome 2.X in your Ubuntu and you can enjoy it for two more years.

Comment: How about Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS? it is still supported.

Comment: @Gowtham Good news , server based install and then ubuntu-desktop installation can offer you two more years supports. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score 3):

See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/87567/124466).
It shows you how to install MATE, a fork of Gnome 2. The links are in the post by Lingeek.