# Where do I get all of the versions of Ubuntu + Flavors

Tags: downloads, release-management

This took me several days to do.  If it doesn't render right, I made and test it for Firefox(with zoom 100%) version 31 since it comes default with Ubuntu.  Please note, that after 14.10 comes out to stable, some of the links will be broken, and I didn't add PPC because it is dead on the desktop. Similarly, it is the same reason why I didn't add Ubuntu Netbook Remix or add the sever edition of Edubuntu. If there are links that don't work please tell me and I will try my best to fix them.

---

**Table of Contents**

- [Mythbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/510651/48372)
- [Edubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/510652/48372)
- [Ubuntu (Desktop, and Server)](https://askubuntu.com/a/510653/48372)
- [Ubuntu Studio](https://askubuntu.com/a/510649/48372)
- [Ubuntu GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/a/510648/48372)
- [Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/510646/48372)
- [Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/510647/48372)
- [Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/510645/48372)

---

**Also See:**

[Ubuntu Flavors on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) 
[How to remove the 'tile' background in the launcher icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450539/how-to-remove-the-tile-background-in-the-launcher-icons/455047#455047)
[How can I get Ubuntu 12.04 to act and feel like Ubuntu 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451822/how-can-i-get-ubuntu-12-04-to-act-and-feel-like-ubuntu-10-04/451845#451845)
[What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)
[How do I make an Ubuntu USB flash drive installer / bootable USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-an-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-installer-bootable-usb)

Comment: Interesting. Just one thing: the "Also See" links seem pretty random.

Comment: The community-wiki discussion comments can be deleted now, I think.

Comment: @Andrew Ubuntu with all flavors is ok and helpful, but why to download/get further versions instead of **only latest & LTS**?

Comment: . . .on the internet (yao ming face)

Comment: Renders very odd with Chrome 36.0 on Win7 Pro 64: http://i.imgur.com/9fgNm5B.png  Still very usable thus far though.

Comment: @MooingDuck Dock yea....  But again I didn't made it for Windows.  I use Chrome too.  http://i.imgur.com/eazLZyu.png, Here it is on Firefox http://i.imgur.com/hUSTinp.png

Comment: @Andrew: Do tables not work in SO answers?  (I have no idea, never tried before)

Comment: @MooingDuck the table tag is banned.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: @mooingDuck Just put a limit on it. meaning you must have rep X to use it. or get it approve.

Comment: The Ubuntu Kylin is a Chinese version with some specific software added. It is also a flavor supported by Canonical.

Comment: @snowhawkyrf yea but this a English base site and not a Chinese one.

Answer (score 1):

All supported Lubuntu releases can be found at the [releases](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/).  11.10 can be found at this [minnor](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/).  For the older unofficial Ubuntu derivative versions they can be found at their released announcements, The directs download links don't work, but the torrent still works. Released announcements: ([11.04](http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-1104-released), [10.10](http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-1010-released), and [10.04](http://lubuntu.net/tags/lubuntu-1004))
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃        Version of Lubuntu        │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Lubuntu 14.04 LTS         │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Lubuntu 14.04 LTS + Mac        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386+mac.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386+mac.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386+mac.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Lubuntu 13.10          │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Lubuntu 13.10 + Mac        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386+mac.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386+mac.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386+mac.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Lubuntu 13.04          │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Lubuntu 13.04 + Mac        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386+mac.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386+mac.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386+mac.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64+mac.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Lubuntu 13.04          │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Lubuntu 12.10 + Mac        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386+mac.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386+mac.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386+mac.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.metalink)  ┃
 
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Lubuntu 12.10          │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Lubuntu 12.04 LTS + Mac        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386+mac.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386+mac.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386+mac.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64+mac.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Lubuntu 12.04 LTS         │   [32-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Lubuntu 11.10 + Mac        │   [32-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386+mac.iso) or [64-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386+mac.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386+mac.metalink) or [64-bit](http://ftp.wh2.tu-dresden.de/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/cdimage/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/lubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64+mac.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Lubuntu 11.04          │      32-bit     │      [32-bit](http://people.ubuntu.com/~gilir/lubuntu-11.04.iso.torrent)     │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Lubuntu 10.10          │      32-bit     │      [32-bit](http://people.ubuntu.com/~gilir/lubuntu-10.10.iso)     │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Lubuntu 10.04 LTS         │      32-bit     │      [32-bit](http://people.ubuntu.com/~gilir/lubuntu-10.10.iso)     │    Not  Available    ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

Answer (score 1):

All Kubuntu releases can be found at the [releases](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/)  and/or [old releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/releases/) pages respectively.
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃       Version of Kubuntu       │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 14.04 LTS        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/kubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/kubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/kubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/kubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/kubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/kubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Kubuntu 13.10         │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.10/release/kubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.10/release/kubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.10/release/kubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.10/release/kubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.10/release/kubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.10/release/kubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Kubuntu 13.04         │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.04/release/kubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.04/release/kubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.04/release/kubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.04/release/kubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.04/release/kubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.04/release/kubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Kubuntu 12.10         │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.10/release/kubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.10/release/kubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.10/release/kubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.10/release/kubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.10/release/kubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.10/release/kubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 12.04 LTS        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/kubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/kubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/kubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/kubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/kubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/kubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Kubuntu 11.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.10/kubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.10/kubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.10/kubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.10/kubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.10/kubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.10/kubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Kubuntu 11.04         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.04/kubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.04/kubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.04/kubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.04/kubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.04/kubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/11.04/kubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Kubuntu 10.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.10/kubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.10/kubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.10/kubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.10/kubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.10/kubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.10/kubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 10.04 LTS        │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.04.2/kubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.04.2/kubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.04.2/kubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.04.2/kubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.04.2/kubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/10.04.2/kubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 9.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.10/kubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.10/kubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.10/kubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.10/kubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.10/kubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.10/kubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 9.04       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.04/kubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.04/kubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.04/kubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.04/kubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.04/kubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/9.04/kubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 8.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.10/kubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.10/kubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.10/kubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.10/kubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.10/kubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.10/kubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Kubuntu 8.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.04.1/kubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.04.1/kubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.04.1/kubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.04.1/kubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.04.1/kubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/8.04.1/kubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 7.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/7.10/kubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/7.10/kubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/7.10/kubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/7.10/kubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 7.04       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/7.04/kubuntu-7.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/7.04/kubuntu-7.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/7.04/kubuntu-7.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/7.04/kubuntu-7.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 6.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/6.10/kubuntu-6.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/6.10/kubuntu-6.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/6.10/kubuntu-6.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/6.10/kubuntu-6.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Kubuntu 6.06 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/6.06.1/kubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/6.06.1/kubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/6.06.1/kubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/6.06.1/kubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 5.10 DVD       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.10/kubuntu-5.10-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.10/kubuntu-5.10-dvd-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Kubuntu 5.10 Install      │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.10/kubuntu-5.10-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.10/kubuntu-5.10-install-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Kubuntu 5.10 Live         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.10/kubuntu-5.10-live-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.10/kubuntu-5.10-live-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Kubuntu 5.05 DVD       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.04/kubuntu-5.04-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.04/kubuntu-5.04-dvd-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Kubuntu 5.04 Install      │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.04/kubuntu-5.04-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.04/kubuntu-5.04-install-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Kubuntu 5.04 Live         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.04/kubuntu-5.04-live-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/5.04/kubuntu-5.04-live-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

Answer (score 1):

All Xubuntu releases can be found at the [releases](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/) and/or [old releases pages](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/) other than the torrents for 7.04, and 6.10 which can be found at this [minnor](http://hex1a4.net/xubuntu/mirror/releases/).
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃       Version of Xubuntu       │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Xubuntu 14.04 LTS        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Xubuntu 13.10         │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.10/release/xubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.10/release/xubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.10/release/xubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.10/release/xubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.10/release/xubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.10/release/xubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Xubuntu 13.04         │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.04/release/xubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.04/release/xubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.04/release/xubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.04/release/xubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.04/release/xubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.04/release/xubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Xubuntu 12.10         │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.10/release/xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.10/release/xubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.10/release/xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.10/release/xubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.10/release/xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.10/release/xubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Xubuntu 12.04 LTS        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/xubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/xubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/xubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/xubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/xubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/xubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Xubuntu 11.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.10/release/xubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.10/release/xubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.10/release/xubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.10/release/xubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.10/release/xubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.10/release/xubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Xubuntu 11.04         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.04/release/xubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.04/release/xubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.04/release/xubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.04/release/xubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.04/release/xubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/11.04/release/xubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Xubuntu 10.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.10/release/xubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.10/release/xubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.10/release/xubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.10/release/xubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.10/release/xubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.10/release/xubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Xubuntu 10.04 LTS        │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.04.2/release/xubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.04.2/release/xubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.04.2/release/xubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.04.2/release/xubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.04.2/release/xubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/10.04.2/release/xubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Xubuntu 9.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.10/release/xubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.10/release/xubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.10/release/xubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.10/release/xubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.10/release/xubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.10/release/xubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Xubuntu 9.04       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.04/release/xubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.04/release/xubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.04/release/xubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.04/release/xubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.04/release/xubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/9.04/release/xubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Xubuntu 8.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.10/release/xubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.10/release/xubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.10/release/xubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.10/release/xubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.10/release/xubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.10/release/xubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Xubuntu 8.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.04.1/release/xubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.04.1/release/xubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.04.1/release/xubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.04.1/release/xubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.04.1/release/xubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/8.04.1/release/xubuntu-8.04.1-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Xubuntu 7.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/gutsy/release/xubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/gutsy/release/xubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/gutsy/release/xubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/gutsy/release/xubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/gutsy/release/xubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/gutsy/release/xubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Xubuntu 7.04       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/7.04/release/xubuntu-7.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/7.04/release/xubuntu-7.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://hex1a4.net/xubuntu/mirror/releases/7.04/release/xubuntu-7.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://hex1a4.net/xubuntu/mirror/releases/7.04/release/xubuntu-7.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Xubuntu 6.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/6.10/release/xubuntu-6.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/releases/6.10/release/xubuntu-6.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://hex1a4.net/xubuntu/mirror/releases/7.10/release/xubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://hex1a4.net/xubuntu/mirror/releases/7.10/release/xubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Xubuntu 6.06 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/6.06.1/xubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/6.06.1/xubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/6.06.1/xubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/6.06.1/xubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/6.06.1/xubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xubuntu/6.06.1/xubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

Answer (score 1):

All Ubuntu Gnome releases can be found at the [releases page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/), and all Ubuntu Gnome Shell Remix releases at [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntu-gs-remix/files/live-image/).
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃    Version of Ubuntu GNOME    │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃      Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS      │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-14.04.1-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu GNOME 13.10       │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.10/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.10/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.10/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.10/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.10/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.10/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu GNOME 13.04       │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-gnome-13.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu GNOME 12.10       │   [32-bit](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/gnome.org/misc/ubuntu-gnome-remix/ubuntu-gnome-12.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/gnome.org/misc/ubuntu-gnome-remix/ubuntu-gnome-12.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes/12.10?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=ubuntu-gnome-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes/12.10?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ubuntu-gnome-12.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃  Ubuntu GNOME Shell Remix 12.04  │   [32-bit](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntu-gs-remix/live-image/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386-gnomeshell-remix.iso?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fubuntu-gs-remix%2Ffiles%2Flive-image%2F12.04%2F&ts=1407643730&use_mirror=softlayer-dal) or [64-bit](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntu-gs-remix/live-image/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386-gnomeshell-remix.iso?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fubuntu-gs-remix%2Ffiles%2Flive-image%2F12.04%2F&ts=1407643730&use_mirror=softlayer-dal)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃  Ubuntu GNOME Shell Remix 11.10  │   [32-bit](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntu-gs-remix/live-image/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386-gnomeshell-remix.iso?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fubuntu-gs-remix%2Ffiles%2Flive-image%2F11.10%2F&ts=1407643911&use_mirror=softlayer-dal) or [64-bit](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntu-gs-remix/live-image/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64-gnomeshell-remix.iso?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fubuntu-gs-remix%2Ffiles%2Flive-image%2F11.10%2F&ts=1407643858&use_mirror=tcpdiag)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

Answer (score 1):

All supported Ubuntu Studio releases can be found at the [releases](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/). 9.10 and 7.10 can be found at the [old releases page](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/releases/) any other version can be found at this [mirror](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases).
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃        Version of Ubuntu Studio       │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu Studio 14.04 LTS        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/14.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-14.04.1-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/14.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-14.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/14.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-14.04.1-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/14.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-14.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/14.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-14.04.1-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/14.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-14.04.1-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃     Ubuntu Studio 13.10     │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.10/release/ubuntustudio-13.10-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.10/release/ubuntustudio-13.10-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.10/release/ubuntustudio-13.10-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.10/release/ubuntustudio-13.10-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.10/release/ubuntustudio-13.10-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.10/release/ubuntustudio-13.10-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃     Ubuntu Studio 13.04     │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.04/release/ubuntustudio-13.04-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.04/release/ubuntustudio-13.04-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.04/release/ubuntustudio-13.04-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.04/release/ubuntustudio-13.04-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.04/release/ubuntustudio-13.04-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.04/release/ubuntustudio-13.04-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃     Ubuntu Studio 12.10     │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.10/release/ubuntustudio-12.10-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.10/release/ubuntustudio-12.10-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.10/release/ubuntustudio-12.10-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.10/release/ubuntustudio-12.10-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.10/release/ubuntustudio-12.10-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.10/release/ubuntustudio-12.10-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu Studio 12.04 LTS        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.04.5/release/ubuntustudio-12.04.5-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.04.5/release/ubuntustudio-12.04.5-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.04.5/release/ubuntustudio-12.04.5-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.04.5/release/ubuntustudio-12.04.5-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.04.5/release/ubuntustudio-12.04.5-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.04.5/release/ubuntustudio-12.04.5-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃     Ubuntu Studio 11.10     │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.10/release/ubuntustudio-11.10-alternate-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.10/release/ubuntustudio-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.10/release/ubuntustudio-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.10/release/ubuntustudio-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.10/release/ubuntustudio-11.10-alternate-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.10/release/ubuntustudio-11.10-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃     Ubuntu Studio 11.04     │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.04/release/ubuntustudio-11.04-alternate-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.04/release/ubuntustudio-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.04/release/ubuntustudio-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.04/release/ubuntustudio-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.04/release/ubuntustudio-11.04-alternate-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/11.04/release/ubuntustudio-11.04-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃     Ubuntu Studio 10.10     │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.10/release/ubuntustudio-10.10-alternate-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.10/release/ubuntustudio-10.10-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.10/release/ubuntustudio-10.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.10/release/ubuntustudio-10.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.10/release/ubuntustudio-10.10-alternate-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.10/release/ubuntustudio-10.10-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu Studio 10.04 LTS        │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.04/release/ubuntustudio-10.04-alternate-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.04/release/ubuntustudio-10.04-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.04/release/ubuntustudio-10.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.04/release/ubuntustudio-10.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.04/release/ubuntustudio-10.04-alternate-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/10.04/release/ubuntustudio-10.04-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu Studio 9.10       │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/9.10/release/ubuntustudio-9.10-alternate-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/9.10/release/ubuntustudio-9.10-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/9.10/release/ubuntustudio-9.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/9.10/release/ubuntustudio-9.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/9.10/release/ubuntustudio-9.10-alternate-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/9.10/release/ubuntustudio-9.10-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu Studio 9.04       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/9.04/release/ubuntustudio-9.04-alternate-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/9.04/release/ubuntustudio-9.04-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/9.04/release/ubuntustudio-9.04-alternate-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/9.04/release/ubuntustudio-9.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/9.04/release/ubuntustudio-9.04-alternate-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/9.04/release/ubuntustudio-9.04-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu Studio 8.10       │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.10/release/ubuntustudio-8.10-alternate-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.10/release/ubuntustudio-8.10-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.10/release/ubuntustudio-8.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.10/release/ubuntustudio-8.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.10/release/ubuntustudio-8.10-alternate-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.10/release/ubuntustudio-8.10-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃      Ubuntu Studio 8.04 LTS     │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-8.04.1-alternate-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-8.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-8.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-8.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-8.04.1-alternate-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/ubuntustudio/releases/8.04.1/release/ubuntustudio-8.04.1-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu Studio 7.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/releases/gutsy/release/ubuntustudio-7.10-alternate-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/releases/gutsy/release/ubuntustudio-7.10-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/releases/gutsy/release/ubuntustudio-7.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntustudio/releases/gutsy/release/ubuntustudio-7.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

Answer (score 1):

All supported Mythbuntu releases can be found at the [releases](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythubuntu/releases/). 9.10 can be found at the [old releases page](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/mythbuntu/releases/9.04/release/) any version else can be found at this [minnor](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/).
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃        Version of Mythbuntu        │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Mythbuntu 14.04 LTS         │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/mythbuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/mythbuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/mythbuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/mythbuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/mythbuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/mythbuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Mythbuntu 12.04 LTS         │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/mythbuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/mythbuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/mythbuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/mythbuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/mythbuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/mythbuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Mythbuntu 11.10          │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.10/release/mythbuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.10/release/mythbuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.10/release/mythbuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.10/release/mythbuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.10/release/mythbuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.10/release/mythbuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Mythbuntu 11.04          │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.04/release/mythbuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.04/release/mythbuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.04/release/mythbuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.04/release/mythbuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.04/release/mythbuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/11.04/release/mythbuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Mythbuntu 10.10          │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.10/release/mythbuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.10/release/mythbuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.10/release/mythbuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.10/release/mythbuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.10/release/mythbuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.10/release/mythbuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Mythbuntu 10.04 LTS         │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.04/release/mythbuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.04/release/mythbuntu-10.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.04/release/mythbuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.04/release/mythbuntu-10.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.04/release/mythbuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/10.04/release/mythbuntu-10.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Mythbuntu 9.10       │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/9.10/release/mythbuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/9.10/release/mythbuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/9.10/release/mythbuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/9.10/release/mythbuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/9.10/release/mythbuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/9.10/release/mythbuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Mythbuntu 9.04       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/mythbuntu/releases/9.04/release/mythbuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/mythbuntu/releases/9.04/release/mythbuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/mythbuntu/releases/9.04/release/mythbuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/mythbuntu/releases/9.04/release/mythbuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/mythbuntu/releases/9.04/release/mythbuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/mythbuntu/releases/9.04/release/mythbuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Mythbuntu 8.10       │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.10/release/mythbuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.10/release/mythbuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.10/release/mythbuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.10/release/mythbuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.10/release/mythbuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.10/release/mythbuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃      Mythbuntu 8.04 LTS      │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.04.1/release/mythbuntu-8.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.04.1/release/mythbuntu-8.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.04.1/release/mythbuntu-8.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.04.1/release/mythbuntu-8.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.04.1/release/mythbuntu-8.04.1-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/mythbuntu/8.04.1/release/mythbuntu-8.04.1-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Mythbuntu 7.10       │   32-bit or 64-bit  │   32-bit or 64-bit  │    Not  Available    ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

Answer (score 1):

All supported Edubuntu releases can be found at the [releases](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/).  10.04 LTS - 11.10 can be found at the this [minnor](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/) Anything else can be found at the
[old releases page](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/).
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃      Version of Edubuntu     │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Edubuntu 14.04 LTS      │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/edubuntu-14.04.1-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/edubuntu-14.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/edubuntu-14.04.1-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/edubuntu-14.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/edubuntu-14.04.1-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/edubuntu-14.04.1-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Edubuntu 13.10        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.10/release/edubuntu-13.10-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.10/release/edubuntu-13.10-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.10/release/edubuntu-13.10-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.10/release/edubuntu-13.10-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.10/release/edubuntu-13.10-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.10/release/edubuntu-13.10-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Edubuntu 13.04        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.04/release/edubuntu-13.04-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.04/release/edubuntu-13.04-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.04/release/edubuntu-13.04-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.04/release/edubuntu-13.04-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.04/release/edubuntu-13.04-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.04/release/edubuntu-13.04-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Edubuntu 12.10        │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.10/release/edubuntu-12.10-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.10/release/edubuntu-12.10-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.10/release/edubuntu-12.10-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.10/release/edubuntu-12.10-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.10/release/edubuntu-12.10-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.10/release/edubuntu-12.10-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Edubuntu 12.04 LTS      │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/edubuntu-12.04.5-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/edubuntu-12.04.5-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/edubuntu-12.04.5-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/edubuntu-12.04.5-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/edubuntu-12.04.5-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/12.04.5/release/edubuntu-12.04.5-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Edubuntu 11.10        │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.10/release/edubuntu-11.10-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.10/release/edubuntu-11.10-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.10/release/edubuntu-11.10-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.10/release/edubuntu-11.10-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.10/release/edubuntu-11.10-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.10/release/edubuntu-11.10-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Edubuntu 11.04        │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.04/release/edubuntu-11.04-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.04/release/edubuntu-11.04-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.04/release/edubuntu-11.04-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.04/release/edubuntu-11.04-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.04/release/edubuntu-11.04-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/11.04/release/edubuntu-11.04-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Edubuntu 10.10        │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.10/release/edubuntu-10.10-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.10/release/edubuntu-10.10-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.10/release/edubuntu-10.10-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.10/release/edubuntu-10.10-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.10/release/edubuntu-10.10-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.10/release/edubuntu-10.10-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Edubuntu 10.04 LTS      │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.04/release/edubuntu-10.04-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.04/release/edubuntu-10.04-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.04/release/edubuntu-10.04-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.04/release/edubuntu-10.04-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.04/release/edubuntu-10.04-dvd-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](ftp://kebo.eepis-its.edu/ubuntu-cd/cdimage/edubuntu/releases/10.04/release/edubuntu-10.04-dvd-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Edubuntu 9.10          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/9.10/release/edubuntu-9.10-addon-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/9.10/release/edubuntu-9.10-addon-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/9.10/release/edubuntu-9.10-addon-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/9.10/release/edubuntu-9.10-addon-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Edubuntu 9.04          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/9.04/release/edubuntu-9.04-addon-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/9.04/release/edubuntu-9.04-addon-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/9.04/release/edubuntu-9.04-addon-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/9.04/release/edubuntu-9.04-addon-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Edubuntu 8.10          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/8.10/edubuntu-8.10-addon-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/8.10/edubuntu-8.10-addon-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/8.10/edubuntu-8.10-addon-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/8.10/edubuntu-8.10-addon-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Edubuntu 8.04 LTS        │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/8.04.1/edubuntu-8.04.1-addon-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/8.04.1/edubuntu-8.04.1-addon-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/8.04.1/edubuntu-8.04.1-addon-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/8.04.1/edubuntu-8.04.1-addon-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Edubuntu 7.10          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/7.10/edubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/7.10/edubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/7.10/edubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/7.10/edubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Edubuntu 7.04          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/7.10/edubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/7.10/edubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/7.10/edubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/7.10/edubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Edubuntu 6.10 Install      │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.10/edubuntu-6.10-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.10/edubuntu-6.10-install-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.10/edubuntu-6.10-install-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.10/edubuntu-6.10-install-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Edubuntu 6.10 Live       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.10/edubuntu-6.10-live-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.10/edubuntu-6.10-live-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.10/edubuntu-6.10-live-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.10/edubuntu-6.10-live-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃      Edubuntu 6.06 LTS DVD     │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Edubuntu 6.06 LTS Install       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-install-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-install-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-install-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃      Edubuntu 6.06 LTS Live      │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-live-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-live-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-live-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/6.06.1/edubuntu-6.06.1-live-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Edubuntu 5.10 Install      │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/5.10/edubuntu-5.10-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edubuntu/5.10/edubuntu-5.10-install-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

Answer (score 1):

All Ubuntu releases can be found at the [releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) and/or [old releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) pages respectively.
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃       Version of Ubuntu (Desktop)      │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 14.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.manifest) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 13.10       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 13.04       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 12.10       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 12.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 11.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 11.04       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 10.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 10.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 9.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 9.04         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 8.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 8.04 LTS       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 7.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 7.04         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 6.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 6.06 LTS       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Ubuntu 5.10 DVD          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 5.10 Install        │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-install-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-install-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-install-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 5.10 Live      │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-live-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-live-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-live-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-live-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Ubuntu 5.04 DVD          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-dvd-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 5.04 Install        │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-install-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 5.04 Live      │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-live-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-live-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 4.10 Install        │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/warty-release-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/warty-release-install-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 4.10 Live      │       [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/warty-release-live-i386.iso)       │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃     Version of Ubuntu (Server)     │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 14.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.manifest) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 13.10       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 13.04       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-i386.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 12.10       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 12.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 11.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 11.04       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 10.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 10.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-amd64.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 9.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-amd64.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-i386.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 9.04         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 8.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 8.04 LTS       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 7.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 7.04         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 6.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 6.06 LTS       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

Answer (score 0):

You can find many of the flavors of Ubuntu Available for torrent download [here.](http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/) Note that no longer supported versions may also be still listed. Ensure that you choose a [supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) version and avoid end of life versions. This approach avoids the "not supported on this tracker" error.