# Converting Ubuntu to Ubuntu Mate Problem!

Tags: mate

I tried converting *Ubuntu* to *Ubuntu mate* using

```
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop
```

and I supposedly removed the Gnome desktop but my screen appears blank. Even in the screen shots it appears but in reality it isn't.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install MATE (the desktop environment)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87040/how-do-i-install-mate-the-desktop-environment)

Comment: What's the issue here? Your desktop looks like it's MATE.

Answer (score 2):

From the official MATE [wiki](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download).

#### How to install MATE in Ubuntu 14.04

Open the terminal, and complete the following steps to enable the appropriate PPAs and install MATE 1.8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

Instead of lightdm use lightdm-gtk-greeter for the login display manager as recommended by the MATE team:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter  
sudo reboot
```

---

#### How to install MATE in Ubuntu 15.10 and newer

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install MATE choose 1 of the 3 apt-get lines below.

1. This will install the base packages required for a minimal MATE
   desktop.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-core
   ```
2. This will install the complete MATE desktop.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment
   ```
3. This will install the complete MATE desktop including a few extras.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-extras
   ```