# install mate desktop core on 18.04

Tags: mate

Is there a way to install the core of the mate desktop on Ubuntu, without all of the extras that come with this method (ubuntu-mate-desktop): [How do I install MATE (the desktop environment)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87040/how-do-i-install-mate-the-desktop-environment)

I can obviously remove all of the extra stuff, libre-office, firefox, shotwell, cheese etc etc, but there is a lot of it.

I have tried installing mate-desktop-environment-core and lightdm, but on entering the mate desktop I get a lot of errors, and nothing seems to work.

Errors are like "The panel encountered an error while loading "BriskMenuFactory::BriskMenu", and no menus or icons are loaded.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found the package `ubuntu-mate-core`, which still installs some stuff you wouldn't really think were part of a desktop per se (like Firefox) but there you go... it works.